# Cannot build Box2D on Linux: linker error

Tags: c++, linux, build, linker, box2d

I'm trying building Box2d v2.3.1 on my Ubuntu (13.10) machine. This is what I'm doing:

```
$ premake4 gmake
$ cd Build/gmake/
$ make
```

But the testbed is not building correctly. I get lots of undefined reference errors for glfw and glew symbols, like this:

```
obj/Debug/Testbed/Main.o: In function `main':
/home/mostafa/.adobe/box2d-2.3.1/Box2D/Build/gmake/../../Testbed/Framework/Main.cpp:458: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
```

I have the development packages for both glfw and glew installed. I also checked the Testbed.make makefile and, since I saw no reference to glfw, added -lglfw to the two places where LIBS variable was defined. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this at last, after lots of searching and tweaking. This is what I did:

1. Make sure you have the very latest version of premake. I had to install premake 4.4 (beta version).
2. Compile and install the latest version of glfw (3.0.4 at the moment) from source. The version in Ubuntu's repositories does not work.
3. Make sure you have glew and xorg development packages. I installed these from Ubuntu's repository: `sudo apt-get install libglew-dev xorg-dev`
4. After running `premake4 gmake` in Box2D directory, go to `Build/gmake` and edit Testbed.make. Change the line `LIBS += $(LDDEPS) -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lglut` into this `LIBS += $(LDDEPS) -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi`.
5. Now run `make`.

Comment: Thanks! That saved me a lot of trouble. I additionally needed `-lXinerama -lXcursor`

Comment: Hmm... This isn't working for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm getting a weird error: #error "No supported window creation API selected" error and then a bunch of other undefined symbol errors.

Comment: I have no idea what that is about, but if you don't care about the testbed, you can try just building Box2D itself: `make -f Box2D.make`

Comment: @Elektito there is no Box2D.make, not anymore atleast.

Comment: I haven't used Box2D for some time. If I get some free time, I'll try to update my answer with the latest release.